# Can the Views Module assign a value to the <title>

Tags: views, 7

Can the Views Module assign a value to the  and/or $title variable?

More specifically, I would like the Views Field: "Content Title" to be the $title.

Comment: You can set the title of a page view manually, not quite sure what you mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a place in the Contextual Filter that lets me set the page title based on the Node ID's URL parameter.

I set options that met my needs in "Context Filters > Content: Nid." Within the Nid options, there are several options for providing a filter value and for overriding the title.

Comment: Could you please explain what you did specifically?